# oh-my-zsh alias color hightlight

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I started use zsh with plugin named "oh-my-zsh", and set up my personal alias in ~/.zshrc.

```
alias ls='ls -aF'
```

and, then

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

but the command `ls` doesn't make the output highlighted. (The command works properly though.)

I don't really get why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

By default the output of `ls` is not colored and neither `-a` (also show hidden files) nor `-F` (append indicator for file type) does change that.

In order to get colored output from `ls` you need to pass the `--color`:

```
ls -aF --color
```

As you are planning to use it in an alias it would be a good idea to set `--color=auto` so that colors are only used when printing to *standard output* but not when redirecting the output (for example with `> SOMEFILE` or `| SOMECOMMAND`):

```
alias ls='ls -aF --color=auto'
```